# Import Libraries into Android Projects

Tags: android, import

i hope someone can help me with the following.

I have 3 Apps and i want to import them into another project in order to test them.
Ok for each of these 3 apps i go to Properties->Android->Checkbox Library ->apply

then i create a Testapp and go to Properties->Android->add Library->apply

But then there are errors considering the R files. 
e.g.:
findViewById(R.id. ...); does not work -> ...cannot be resolved or is not a field!
If i test them locally everything works, but these apps should be integrated to another main-app later and i want to know if everything is ok.

Thanks
hannes

Comment: R.id that didn't work is from ur current porject or from the libraries ?

Comment: if R.id is from another library prefix it with the package that it came from like this com.mypackage.R.id

Comment: that does not work -.- but if i look into the generated R files they are automatically changed, if i import them as library; they are not equal to the former R files from each former Android Project

Comment: open the Properties for the project and select the "is Library" checkbox. Other application projects can now reference the existing project as a library project.

Comment: okey include into you manifest file all the library using <uses-library android:name="com.package..."
              android:required="true" />

Comment: same error as before i did it like in this tutorial manifest file has all activities of all classes and uses library. i don't know what to do else

Comment: all R files in the test project are beeing overwritten by one former r-file but ALL R-Files are in other packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to properties of one of the project: java-build-path->projects->add 
add dependencies of all other projects